# Reshape MATLAB vector in Row-wise manner

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Say I have a matrix `a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];`, how do I reshape it in a row-wise manner for example
`reshape(a, 2, 3)` to yield

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

rather than the default column-wise result produced by MATLAB of:

```
1 3 5 
2 4 6
```

I believe this is a trivial task which probably has an inbuilt function to achieve this. I have already implemented a function that does this perfectly... however, is there a shorter, neater and more MATLAB way? Thanks.

```
function y = reshape2(x, m, n) 
  y = zeros(m, n);

  ix = 0; 
  for i = 1:m
     for j = 1:n
         ix = ix + 1;
         y(i, j) = x(ix);
     end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this?

`reshape(a, 3, 2)'`

Comment: This solution fails for ND array.
Consider a 3D array 2x3x4 
`a = [1:2*3*4]`

Comment: This solution fails for ND array.
Consider a 3D array 2x3x4 
`a = [1:2*3*4]`

Expected to be reshaped as follows,

`b(:,:,1) = 
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12

b(:,:,2) =
13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24`

Answer (score 3):

The general way to reshape an `m*n` matrix A to a `p*k` matrix B in a row-wise manner is:

```
c=reshape(A',1,m*n) 
B=reshape(c,k,p)' 
example: m=3 n=4 , p=6, q=2
A=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12] 
c=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12] 
B=[1 2 ; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8; 9 10; 11 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed reshape(A',cols,rows)'

( reshape(a', 3, 2)' in your example)

Comment: Cheers for deleting your question just now - I had just spent 10 minutes preparing an answer. I might have been useful for someone else. (I thought it was a good question).

Comment: Oh I'll re-post the question then @MatthewTaylor