# Discatenate a column vector to get back to its original square matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I had to convert an n x n matrix to n^2 x 1 column vector for ease of some operations. Now, that the operations are done, how do I return to the n x n form from the n^2 x 1 vector.

It is supposed to be opposite of this: [concatenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Qkg.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape MATLAB vector in Row-wise manner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592386/reshape-matlab-vector-in-row-wise-manner)

Comment: If you read [the following documentation pages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html), everything should be clear. Notice that in your image the result is the transpose of the _concatenation_ of the rows. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reshape()` function:

```
//M is your n^2 x 1 column vector, A is your nxn matrix that you want to recover   
A = reshape(M, [n n])
```

If your n x n matrix is 3x3, then:

```
A = reshape(M, [3 3])
```

For more info: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html